# MySQL Best practice setting default value or not?

Tags: mysql, default

Good day,

I have a question.
Recently moved my project to a new host where MySQL strict mode had been enabled.

Now I got hundreds of messages that no default value had been set for the database field.

But now the following. I can disable strict mode.
And have it to work without issues. My question remains, what's the benefit?

Does it improve database speed to have a default value set for every field?
Or reliability?

To my simple logic no value simply means NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. Strict mode in this case forces you to explicitly set your default values, which is a good practice. Otherwise you will rely on mysql's internal logic to derive the default value. What happens if that logic changes and you don't notice it?

Comment: Sounds legit.
I do think however that giving this as an error in strict mode is pretty much over the top. But we all know that MySQL could use a massive revamp :-D

Comment: I disagree on this point. Actually, I think mysql should remove the non-strict mode option completely and force programmers and DBAs to explicitly efine default values. Btw, the strict mode operation is in line with how other major rdbms products (oracle, ms sql) operate.